# correct way of using CompletableFuture on void method

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, completable-future

I have the below use case :

1. read a file from s3
2. map each line to request object
3. call a void method to do api call
4. In this void method, I store a list requests with successful and unsuccessful result
5. send an email with the stats, and do some u

To enhance performance I am using  CompletableFuture. Below is the code that I have now:

```
List<CompletableFuture<Void>> linesProcessed = listOfLineReadFromFile.stream()
                .map(
                        lineReadFromList ->
                                CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> handleLine(lineReadFromList), executorService))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        linesProcessed.stream()
                .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This is working as expected. But I have following questions:

1. Why should I be collecting a list of `CompletableFuture<Void>`given that it's void.
2. I need to do below, because it is not messing up with any of the steps mentioned above. But, again why to stream on void?

`linesProcessed.stream().map(CompletableFuture::join).collect(Collectors.toList());`

3. linesProcessed.get() -> doesn't return the desired result, messes up the process to send email and storing stats.

Is there a better way to use CompletableFuture for this scenario?

Comment: `Void` just means it doesn't return any result. You should be able to replace the stream with `linesProcessed.forEach(CompletableFuture::join)`.

Comment: correct. that can be done. But still, why do I need to store a list of void in the first place?  List<CompletableFuture<Void>> linesProcessed . And is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can store them as `CompletableFuture<?>` if you want.

Comment: But still will have to do: listOfLineReadFromFile.stream()
                .map(
                        lineReadFromList ->
                                CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> handleLine(lineReadFromList), executorService))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
?

Comment: Presumably. But I'm not sure why you're asking us what your code needs to do.

Comment: @user16320675 That'll run them sequentially.

Comment: @user16320675 The whole point of CompletableFuture is to run things in parallel. As far as I understand, Stream.parallel() only splits the stream into parallel chunks; it's not guaranteed to parallelize each element.

Comment: @shmosel as per logs, the calls are happening in parallely. The processing time is significantly down. So ,I think the work is being down. My only concern is that if there is a better way.

Comment: The only purpose of calling `join` on a `CompletableFuture<Void>`, is to wait for the completion, so, of course, you don’t need to collect the returned `null`s. You can achieve the same with `listOfLineReadFromFile.stream() .map(line -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> handleLine(line), executorService)) .toList() .forEach(CompletableFuture::join);` Note that in this case, the intermediate list is necessary to ensure that all actions are commenced first, before starting to wait for completion.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `CompletableFuture.allOf( listOfLineReadFromFile.stream() .map(line -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> handleLine(line), executorService)) .toArray(CompletableFuture<?>[]::new) ).join();`